# Unity2D no bullet trail while shooting at enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

https://gyazo.com/0a29918f513316fc4143a5ff76095bd3

This is how it looks visually.

That's my shooting weapon code:

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

public float fireRate = 0;
public float maxDamage = 10;
public LayerMask whatToHit ;

public Transform BulletTrailPrefab;
public Transform MuzzleFlashPrefab;
public Transform HitPrefab;
float timeToSpawnEffect = 0;
public float effectSpawnRate = 10;

float timeToFire = 0;
Transform firePoint;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    firePoint = transform.FindChild("FirePoint");   
    if(firePoint == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No FirePoint");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(fireRate == 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }else
    {
        if(Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > timeToFire)
        {
            timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
    Vector2 firePointPosition = new Vector2(firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePointPosition,mousePosition - firePointPosition,100,whatToHit);

    Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, (mousePosition - firePointPosition) * 100,Color.cyan);
    if(hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, hit.point, Color.red);
        Enemy enemy = hit.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if(enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.DamageEnemy(Random.Range(maxDamage/2,maxDamage));
          //  Debug.Log("we hit" + hit.collider.name + " and did: " + maxDamage + " damage");        
        }
    }

    if (Time.time >= timeToSpawnEffect)
    {
        Vector3 hitPos;
        Vector3 hitNormal;

        if (hit.collider == null)
        {
            hitPos = (mousePosition - firePointPosition) * 30;
            hitNormal = new Vector3(9999, 9999, 9999);
        }
        else
        {
            hitPos = hit.point;
            hitNormal = hit.normal;
        }

        Effect(hitPos,hitNormal);
        timeToSpawnEffect = Time.time + 1 / effectSpawnRate;
    }
}

void Effect(Vector3 hitPos, Vector3 hitNormal)
{
    Transform trail = Instantiate(BulletTrailPrefab,firePoint.position,firePoint.rotation) as Transform;
    LineRenderer lr = trail.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    if(lr != null)
    {
        // Set positions
        lr.SetPosition(0, firePoint.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, hitPos);
    }

    Destroy(trail.gameObject, 0.035f);

    if (hitNormal != new Vector3(9999, 9999, 9999))
    {
        Transform hitParticle = Instantiate(HitPrefab, hitPos, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.right,hitNormal)) as Transform;
        hitParticle.parent = transform.parent;
        Destroy(hitParticle.gameObject, 0.3f);
    }       


    Transform clone = Instantiate(MuzzleFlashPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    clone.parent = firePoint;
    float size = Random.Range(0.3f, 0.5f);
    clone.localScale = new Vector3(size, size, size);
    Destroy(clone.gameObject, 0.02f);
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

I've been trying to figure it out what's wrong for hours now. Checked the code just too many times, don't know how to google this problem. Just can't understand why it's hitting everything except that spaceship..

Don't know what other information you might need so tell me if you need something more.

Comment: What is the Z value of the spaceships transform?

Comment: 1, I suppose if it were on different value I couldn't even deal damage to it, or could I ?

Comment: try and make it 0 or -1 and see if the trail shows up. Small chance that it is that.

Comment: Sadly it didn't

Comment: Ah, nightmare. It will most likely be something to do with the depth of the bullet when it is targeting the space ship. Maybe try and pause the game when a bullet is in the air, and then locate it in the scene view. Check to see if it's depth/positioning is set to something strange.

Comment: It's too fast to move my cursor to pause button >.<

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P will pause the game in the inspector. (Command+Shift+P on mac)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/JyIi8ZV.png here how it looks

Comment: Could you remove this piece of code from your `Script`:
`else
        {
            hitPos = hit.point;
            hitNormal = hit.normal;
        }`
And test again please.

Comment: Effect(hitPos, hitNormal); this line then don't work